# What are the permissions needed for an account to start a SP2013 Workflow by Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, powershell

I need to run a SP2013 workflow on a number of list item as a batch job.  I would like to use Powershell to do this as I would be able to selectively run the workflow on items that have specific column values.

I've read that running this Powershell script to call the SP2013 workflow on these items shouldn't be run by a farm account.  What permissions should an account that is running this Powershell script have?  If it's not using the farm account, I get a message from Powershell ISE that the 'The local farm is not accessible.  Cmdlets with FeatureDependencyId are not registered' when using Add-PSSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.Powershell

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to execute this in SharePoint Management Shell then just right click on the SP Management Shell and click Run As An Administrator. You may also need an account who has Shell Admin access permission.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg490648.aspx